# How Change image name(num) on hover? from "picture" to "picture01" ... "picture10" .jpg

Tags: javascript, html

How Change image name(num) on hover? from "picture" to "picture01" ... "picture10" .jpg
On an increasing basis, and if you remove the cursor, it resets to the original image, each block is independent

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/001/picture.jpg"</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/002/picture.jpg"</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the hover with a mouse over event listener in js:

```
test.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
  // change the src of the image here
  img.src = "file.png";

}, false);
```

Comment: I need +1 to 10 to be added gradually to the name

Comment: I understand, picture will change to picture01? Then the other to 02 - which is the default picture of it?

Comment: It was
  ../images/picture01.jpg
 in Hover This block after 05 sec 
  change 01.jpg to 02.jpg
 After 1 sec 
  change 02.jpg to 03.jpg
 After 1.5 sec
  change 03.jpg to 04.jpg
 ....
 After n sec
 change 09.jpg to 10.jpg and again